# Unable to create ref dynamically in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am rendering a list and then a sublist within that. I want to have a ref to my inner list which will be named something like `list-{id}`. However, I am not able to achieve this.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<ul class="scrollable-list" ref="getScrollableRef(company.id)">
  <li v-for="operation in getOperations(company.id)">
    {{company.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I inspect the `$refs` object:

```
$vm0.$refs
Object {getScrollableRef(company.id): Array(13)}
```

I think for some reason the value is not being evaluated. Has anyone faced this?

**Edit:** I am trying to solve this problem https://github.com/egoist/vue-mugen-scroll/issues/14

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you are specifying that the `ref` should literally be named `"getSchoolableRef(componany.id)"`. That's why the `$refs` object contains an `getScrollableRef(company.id)` property with an array of 13 elements as its value.

If you want to use the result of the `getSchoolableRef` method as the name of the `ref`, you can use `v-bind` or the shorthand colon:

```
<ul class="scrollable-list" :ref="getScrollableRef(company.id)">
```

As you mentioned, `$refs` is not reactive and changing the bound value once the component has initialized will not update the property name in `$refs`. But, you can dynamically set the name of the `ref` when the component initializes.

Comment: It says here that we should not attempt to bind ref. Is this correct?
https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: Good catch. I'll update the answer. That says that `$refs` is not reactive and won't update if you change the bound value updates. But, I don't see a problem with using `v-bind` to initialize the ref name.